# Removing from ArrayList using String.valueOf(s.charAt(i))

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I know many variations of this question have been asked before but it is not working for me.Let's say I have an ArrayList called `list` and a String `s`and i want to remove add or remove a character in `s` based on a condition, it works perfectly when i add a character to the list but it doesn't work when i remove the character. For example when i use `list.remove(String.valueOf('c'))`it works but when i use `list.remove(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i))` it doesn't. 
 Here is an example

```
 for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){

   if(condition){list.add(s.charAt(i)}

   else{
      list.remove(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
       }
     }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please post a [mcve] demonstrating the specific problem.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: it's just not removing it from the list. no error

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: As it stands now, you're adding `Character`s and removing `String`s. No way that's going to work.

Comment: when i do it without adding String.valueOf, it gives me array index out of bounds exception.

Comment: Show detail log and complete code .

Comment: @shmosel you were right i needed to change it to char and add (new Character(s.charAt(i)) for it to work. Thanks.

Comment: `add(s.charAt(i))` would work equally well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your code is not working because in java a String "X" is not the same as a Character 'X'... let me explain:

if you take a look in the remove method of the ArrayList, you will find this:

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            if (elementData[index] == null) {
                fastRemove(index);
                return true;
            }
    } else {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
                fastRemove(index);
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but the important part is here:

```
 if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
            fastRemove(index);
            return true;
 }
```

now, since [String.valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-) returns a  String object then you are telling your code to remove a String of a list of chars... that instruction will always fail because `o.equals(elementData[index])` return in that case false...